# To use a self join, union or some other operation(s) on an SQL table with bi-direction graph information

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table:

```
 talker | listener | minutes 
--------+----------+---------
 sue    | rob      |       3
 sue    | jan      |       2
 jan    | sue      |       1
 rob    | sue      |       7
 jan    | sue      |       4
 rob    | sue      |       6
 rob    | jan      |       5
 dan    | jan      |       5
 sue    | abe      |       9
```

What is the best way to determine the total conversation time for each person? Example:

```
name | minutes
-----+--------
 dan |       5
 abe |       9
 rob |      21
 sue |      32
 jan |      17
```

(Assume I added correctly.)

Also, I'd like to know if it's possible to make the initial table double in size with a self join or other mechanics. (Goal being to make a table with `select talker as name, minutes` unioned with `select listener as name, minutes`).

Some help:

```
create table discussions(talker varchar(10), listener varchar(10), minutes INT);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('sue', 'rob', 3);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('sue', 'jan', 2);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('jan', 'sue',  1);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('rob', 'sue',  7);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('jan', 'sue',  4);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('rob', 'sue',  6);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('rob', 'jan',  5);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('dan', 'jan',  5);
insert into discussions(talker, listener, minutes) values ('sue', 'abe',  9);
```

Comment: `Select  talker as name, sum(minutes) from( select talker ,minutes from x union all select listener minutes from x) group by talker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, sum(minutes)
from
(
  select talker as name, minutes from discussions
  union all 
  select listener, minutes from discussions
) tmp
group by name
```

Comment: Is it more efficient to sum the minutes / group by in the inner selects?

Comment: @codeaperature . . . You would need to test that on your system and your data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - But ... that is the question I'm asking the experts - `best way`

Comment: @codeaperature Experts can't know if your tables are set up to make the most out of a given solution, but with proper indexes, SQL engines are more efficient at doing fewer aggregations on 1 large dataset (this solution) than multiple aggregations on multiple smaller datasets (my solution)

Comment: @ Mithrandir - That's info I wanted to know ... less agg's on 1 larger dataset is generally better. Your answer confuses me a little as to whether it's better than this solution or not tho. I was asking if your answer is better that this one. (Sidebar: My table setup was provided in the question - No indexes.)

Answer (score 0):

Using join method using can achieve the same result:

```
     SELECT (COALESCE(TALKER_MINS, 0) + COALESCE(LISTENER_MINS, 0)) AS MINUTES, COALESCE(X.TALKER, Y.LISTENER) as NAME FROM (
SELECT SUM(MINUTES) TALKER_MINS, A.TALKER FROM discussions A GROUP BY TALKER) X 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT SUM(MINUTES) LISTENER_MINS, A.listener FROM discussions A GROUP BY listener) Y
ON X.TALKER = Y.LISTENER ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Tried and got: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NAME"
LINE 2: NVL(X.TALKER, Y.LISTENER) NAME FROM (`

Comment: Sorry this for Oracle, so might be it wont work in Postgres

Comment: Edited the answer for Postgres NVL function replaced with COALESCE for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different logic using CTE. It most likely will perform worse than the accepted answer, but I am leaving it in here so you can test it yourself--either as is or rewriting it using a temp table or a subquery.

```
with cte (name, minutes) as

(select talker, sum(minutes)
 from discussions
 group by talker
 union all
 select listener, sum(minutes)
 from discussions
 group by listener)
  
select name, sum(minutes)
from cte
group by name;
```